# A convex function must has an "asymptote"?

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, convergence-divergence, convex-analysis

$y=f(x)$ is a [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition), increasing real function. Could we **prove that**:

> There exists $k\in[0,+\infty]$ such that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f'(x)=k$.

---

**Intuitive Motivation:**

I am trying to solve an interesting problem stating that any convex function must has an "asymptote" with "slope" in $(-\infty,+\infty]$. Well, it is not so formal because if the slope $k=+\infty$, then there isn't really a fixed asymptote line as defined in classic textbooks.

I've learnt some about convex functions but never observed this fact. It seems really  intuitive.

---

**My try:**

The problem seems equivalent to show that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f''(x)$ either converges to zero, or $f'(+\infty)=+\infty$!

1. If $f''(x)$ converges to zero, then $f'(x)$ can converge to one of the positive real number.
2. If $f''(x)$ converges to other positive numbers, then $f'(+\infty)=+\infty$.
3. If $f''(x)$ diverges, I think it is still the case that $f'(+\infty)=+\infty$, but I don't know how to show this. I might be wrong.

Any reference will help.

Comment: A example will be $-e^x$

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi I guess you mean $e^x$? the derivative approaches $+\infty$

Comment: As $f$ is convex, $f'$ (presuming it exists) is monotonically non-decreasing, so it must have a limit (real or $+\infty$) as $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: I agree with @StinkingBishop. In addition, it's possible for the derivative of a convex function not to exist at countably many points (take $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k}|x-k|$ for instance) and thus for $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$ not to exist at all.

Comment: @StinkingBishop How to prove that the limit converges at infinity? Does monotonicity implies convergence?

Comment: Either the function ($f'$ in this case) is bounded from above, in which case its limit is its supremum, or it is unbounded, in which case its limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Ok I guess to get it